# consumes not detecting the file extension - REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to upload a file from a client to my application.

this is my controller's method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
            MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity saveFile(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @RequestBody MultipartFile file) {

... 

}
```

But when I try to upload an image with the right extension I get 415 HTTP code : Support type not supported.

Even though when I removes the "consumes" attributes and try again, the file is well uploaded successfully.

and I've checked the `content-type` it was equal to `image/png`.

EDIT ::
 Postman screen :

[image]

Comment: could you share your client code too?

Comment: I'm just using Postman to test my webservices

Comment: So, could you share your postman request screenshot?

Comment: Yes and that's what in the variable `MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE`

Comment: I've edited my post and added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I think MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA must be used. Content type is just a request header and uploading does not set file extension in the header.

If you need to check content you can use apache Tika

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>

Tika tika = new Tika();
String contentType = tika.detect(someInputStreamHere);
```

then you can check whether the content type extracted from real bytes is allowed or not.